# Definite Intergral of $x\cos(x)\sqrt{x^2+1}$ without a calculator

Tags: calculus

I'm evaluating the area of a parametric function and I'm stuck at this point.
$$S=2\pi \int_{0}^{2\pi} x\cos(x)\sqrt{x^2+1} \mathrm{d}x.$$
Is there anyway to work this problem further without a calculator?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Use MathJax to edit your question

Comment: You can use for example this tool: http://www.texpaste.com/

Comment: What's the original function you had?  It might be easier to integrate that.

Comment: I would be surprised if this can be computed as an elementary closed form. What is the original problem?

Comment: @SangchulLee. Even using special functions, I guess.

Comment: What kind of curve are you dealing with here? Based on the magnitude of its derivative, you have that $\mathbf r’(t) = 2 \pi \langle x^2 \cos x, x \cos x \rangle.$ But there must be a better way to parametrize this curve.

Answer (score 1):

There is probably no antiderivative. So, basically, you are asking to perform a numerical integration without calculator.

The only thing I am able to think about is to write $\sqrt{1+x^2} \sim x$ and then
$$S=2\pi \int_{0}^{2\pi} x\cos(x)\sqrt{x^2+1} \,dx \sim 2\pi \int_{0}^{2\pi} x^2\cos(x) \,dx$$
Integration by parts gives
$$\int x^2\cos(x) \,dx=\left(x^2-2\right) \sin (x)+2 x \cos (x)$$ and then
$$S \sim 8\pi^2\approx 78.9568$$ while numerical integration lead to $77.7680$.

Answer (score 0):

This question is not possible to integrate without a calculator.  It was in the instructions for the assignment and I overlooked it. Here is the original problem for anyone curious.
https://www.bartleby.com/solution-answer/chapter-102-problem-57e-calculus-early-transcendentals-8th-edition/9781285741550/set-up-an-integral-that-represents-the-area-of-the-surface-obtained-by-rotating-the-given-curve/4001ed01-52f2-11e9-8385-02ee952b546e